# Is there a synonym to "Companion Book"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for companion books, and to look for them I would like to know all of the synonyms.

> The Oxford Companion to English Literature

Comment: What type of book? there can be "student exercises" or "vol 1" and "vol 2" or "part 1" and "part 2" or "theory" and "examples  or practice" etc

Comment: theory book mostly, or encyclopedic books.

Comment: So "Vol 1 A to As" then "Vol 2 Asa to Bb" etc is possible - based on looking at the French Language Encyclopaedia on my shelf...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that this sort of work doesn't have much in the way of general terms that mean specifically *this*. Not all books called "**companion to**" are going to be specifically this encyclopaedic style, and not all in this style will be called *companions*. Other terms that I would expect to produce similar books include:

- **guide**, usually *guide to SUBJECT*
- **reference**, may be *reference to SUBJECT*, *SUBJECT: a reference*, or other forms
- **encyclopaedia**, usually *encyclopaedia of SUBJECT* (may also be spelled *encyclopedia*)
- **dictionary**, often *dictionary of SUBJECT* (we have a *Dictionary of Modern History, 1789-1945* on our bookshelves that is in this style)

These will also find an awful lot of things that aren't in the same format as well, though.